# Get specific values out of dictionary with multiple keys in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to extract multiple ISINs out of a output.json file in python.

The output.json file looks like the following:

{'A1J780': {'ter': '0.20%', 'wkn': 'A1J780', 'isin': 'IE00B88DZ566'}, 'A1J7W9': {' 'ter': '0.20%', 'isin': 'IE00B8KMSQ34'}, 'LYX0VQ': {'isin': 'LU1302703878'}, 'A2AMYP': {'ter': '0.22%',  'savingsPlan': None, 'inceptionDate': '02.11.16', 'fundSize': '48', 'isin': 'IE00BD34DB16'}}
...

My current approach is the following:

```
 with open('output.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    value_list = list()
    for i in data:
         value_list.append(i['isin'])
    print(value_list)
```

However, I receive the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/placeholder.py", line 73, in <module>
    value_list.append(i['isin'])
                      ~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

I would highly appreciate your input!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data.values()` as target in for loop to iterate over the JSON objects. Doing a loop over `data` iterates over the keys which is a string value (e.g. "A1J780").

```
data = {
    'A1J780': {'ter': '0.20%', 'wkn': 'A1J780', 'isin': 'IE00B88DZ566'},
    'A1J7W9': {'ter': '0.20%', 'isin': 'IE00B8KMSQ34'}
}
value_list = []
for i in data.values():
    value_list.append(i['isin'])
print(value_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['IE00B88DZ566', 'IE00B8KMSQ34']
```

If the `isin` key is not present in any of the dictionary objects then you would need to use `i.get('isin')` and check if the value is not None otherwise `i['isin']` would raise an exception.